# How to find out missing or deleted site collections in Staging Environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, auditing, staging

We have created  some 40+ site collections in staging environment.On the dev machines we used to development and deploy the wsps and run the powershell scripts in UAT to create site collections and sites.Yesterday when we started  doing  normal testing of our portal,we found that ROOT site colelction and another important site collection were missing.I checked the event viewer logs information in the UAT box.But did not find anything mysterious.Can anyone help how to find out why this happened?This happened within 12 hrs of time.If I enable Auditing on this SP Farm, will it help me to find what happened on those sites.I checked the content database of one missing sitecollection.Its intact.Later customer reported us that they faced some issues in their SAN storage environment.I am not able to find the link between these two.
Note-Audit logging was not enabled in the SP application.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the site collection was deleted, the Site Collection object is removed from **SPSite** and able to access using **SPDeletedSite**.

To get the deleted site collection details, we have to give Site Collection Id or server relative url as input.

**PowerShell command to Get the deleted Site Collection:**

```
Get-SPDeletedSite < Site Collection server relative URL >

Get-SPDeletedSite –Identity < Site Collection ID >
```

Comment: thanks. but when i ran the above command i am not able to see the details of the deleted site.Even my  content db was also not avaialble in my DB box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ...

**Get-SPDeletedSite & Remove-SPDeletedSite**

Use Remove SPDeletedSite only if you need it.

To get the site collection use the following command

```
>Get-SPDeletedSite
```

You'll see the site (or sites) listed, like this:

```
WebApplicationId   : 009c1289-392b-43a6-8222-146117074738
DatabaseId         : 88efc46f-5a2b-4171-81cb-7577da65bac3
SiteSubscriptionId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SiteId             : 86d69f7e-3a9e-4f65-8eba-550d77f93a18
Path               : /sites/collaboration
Scheme             : Http
Url                : http://portal/sites/collaboration
DeletionTime       : 2014-02-21 11:14:18

WebApplicationId   : c73bb367-d329-4ef2-aef7-323ce207d2a9
DatabaseId         : aeb2d6ab-9f9b-493f-aefc-797d4b591f43
SiteSubscriptionId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SiteId             : 9d0ed313-0353-4cec-817a-a491a8c5fc26
Path               : /
Scheme             : Http
Url                : http://portal/
DeletionTime       : 2014-02-19 15:27:37
```

And if you wish to remove any of the site collection in future Copy the SiteId and run the following command if any only when you need it

```
 Remove-SPDeletedSite –Identity SiteId
```

e.g. `Remove-SPDeletedSite –Identity 9d0ed313-0353-4cec-817a-a491a8c5fc26`